# How to merge or rebase the branch workflow

Tags: git

There is an GitHub repo `g` I have forked a copy `f` and have branches `f:a` and `f:b`. I have an ongoing PR `f:a`->`g:master`

I wanted to fetch change so I used the GitHub's fetch changes which actually uses `pull` with `merge`. I want to use `rebase` from now so the commit history stays clean and relevant to my PR, but I don't understand how the workflow should be.

- should I rebase the forked master `f:master` wrt `g:master` first or
- should I rebase the branch `f:a` wrt `g:master`

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to rebase whatever you want to rebase: if branch f:a is the one you are working on, don't worry about the others.

Git doesn't see branches as a hierarchy, each one is just a pointer which can point anywhere, so whether f:master is up to date - or even whether it exists at all - won't make any difference to your pull request.